# Determining the number of objects in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am making a book application. To move to the next topic I am using a button. The Button works as it moves to the next topic, but at the end of the file my application gets the message obj_fatal and it crashes. If I knew how many objects there are in my NSArray then the problem will be solved. I am getting the details from a .plist file and storing it in to a array.

So if any one knows how, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.
Viral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-[NSArray count]`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you prefer the look and feel of a property, you can do the following, assuming your NSArray is called myArray:

```
myArray.count
```

which is the same as @shosti's method, but looks different.

The difference is readability.  So you could have:

```
if ([myArray count] > 0)
```

or you could have

```
if (myArray.count > 0)
```

which probably looks neater.

Both answers are good and correct.  Whichever you choose depends on your coding style.  As I said, both ways accomplish the same thing and call the same getter method.

Hope that helps.